# How to paraphrase “I feel cheated!”

Tags: phrase-requests

What is another way to phrase the following:

> I feel cheated!

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please edit the question to provide more information, in order to enable a quality answer -- for instance, what is this in reaction to? How do you intend to use it? Do read our [help on asking questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Ensure that you include all the research you have done already, and indicate what isn't clear in the information you found. This ensures that people don't repeat the work you have already done, and can address exactly what you're unsure of.

Comment: Look for the word "cheat" in thesaurus and replace it. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, 
"I feel betrayed", 
"I feel deceived", 
"I feel ripped off", 
"I feel like I have been taken for a ride / scammed / duped / conned / screwed".